# Issue Decoding a Set for Tableview

Tags: swift

I am using the following struct that conforms to Codable to represent my data within a Set, I then take this set encode it into a JSON Array that looks like the following `[{"myexample":"Example5","id":3}]`

**Struct and Encoding:**

```
struct Model : Codable, Hashable {
    var myexample: String?
    var id: Int?
}

var mySet: Set<Model> = []
mySet.insert(Model(myexample: "Example4", id: 3))

do {
    let json = try JSONEncoder().encode(mySet)
    print(String(data: json, encoding: .utf8)!)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

How can I inversely decode this array using the following function?

**Currently getting this error:**

> Value of type 'Set' has no member 'utf8'

```
func processArray(array:Set<Model> = []) {
    do{
        let mydata = Data(array.utf8.data)
        let decoded = try  JSONDecoder().decode([Model].self,from: mydata)
        print(decoded)
    }catch let jsonErr {
        print(jsonErr)
    }
}
```

Comment: You seem confused. Isn't `processArray` supposed to take a JSON `String` as a parameter? Otherwise what are you decoding exactly?

Comment: What are you trying to do when you write `Data(array.utf8.data)`? This makes no sense, so we need to know what you want to achieve.

Comment: Yes I am trying to accept a JSON array and decode it using the Model Struct - how can I have the function accept JSON String?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSON is a string format so a *JSON array* is also string

```
func processJSON(_ json: String) {
    do{
        let mydata = Data(json.utf8)
        let decoded = try JSONDecoder().decode(Set<Model>.self,from: mydata)
        print(decoded)
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
}
```

Comment: Understood, I appreciate your help. Can you please take a look at one other question I had? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70701244/index-out-of-range-when-presenting-json-data-in-tableview