# Index out of range when presenting JSON data in tableview

Tags: swift

I am having issue identifying and changing the color of tableview rows that contain the same `name` value in both [ListStruct] which contains the inital data for the tableview rows, and `[HighlightStruct]` which contains the `name` that need to be highlighted.

**Initially I have the following JSON array populate my tableview:**

```
private func fetchJSON() {
        guard let url = URL(string: "www.test.com")
            else { return }
        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        request.httpBody = "test=test1".data(using: .utf8)
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, _, error in
            guard let data = data else { return }
            do {
                self.structure = try JSONDecoder().decode([ListStruct].self,from:data)
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                }}catch {print(error)}}.resume()}


struct ListStruct: Codable {
    let id: String
    let wo: String
    let name: String
    let type: String
}
```

**Then the same view controller has a second JSON array that is decoded below for highlighting:**

```
func processJSON(_ json: String) {
    do{
        let mydata = Data(json.utf8)
        let decoded = try JSONDecoder().decode(Set<HighlightStruct>.self,from: mydata)
        print(decoded)
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
}

struct HighlightStruct: Codable, Hashable {
    var id: Int
    var name: String
}
```

**Applying Highlight**

```
var mySet: Set<HighlightStruct> = []
var highlightedStructure = [HighlightStruct]()
var structure = [ListStruct]()


 override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        
        
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "myCell") as! myCell
        
        let portfolio: ListStruct
        portfolio = structure[indexPath.row]
        
        let highlight: HighlightStruct
        highlight = highlightedStructure[indexPath.row]
        
        //Highlight those that match in both arrays
        if highlight.wo == portfolio.wo {
               cell.backgroundColor = .yellow
        }
```

> Getting index out of range

Comment: It's unclear when `processJSON` is executed. One of the arrays is empty when `cellForRow` is called the first time. You have to ensure that the arrays `structure` and `highlightedStructure` have exactly the same size.

Comment: HighlightedStructure will never have the same size, in terms of data. Initially it will always be empty as nothing in the table will need to be highlighted. With a few user actions the highlightedstructure will begin to populate.

Comment: Then you must change your design. `structure[indexPath.row]` and subsequent `highlightedStructure[indexPath.row]` requires that the arrays have the same size.

Comment: ProcessJSON is executed through a delegate property when an action is preformed in a different view controller. Only then does highlightedstructure get populated with data

Comment: What can be done to the design? I really appreciate your help

Comment: There is not enough information for a reasonable suggestion.

Comment: Is there perhaps a way to apply the cell background color change to those cells that contain a name that matches those in a simple string array? [String]()

Comment: If `structure` is the array that holds the content of the table view then you can not use `indexPath.row` to access another array. You need to use `filter`, `first(where:)` or similar to check if an element exists in both arrays.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting **index out of range** error because your **arrays are empty or there is no index that exist in your arrays**. Maybe you can check your service call, the arrays could not be filled properly.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure ur two list count is same size, or process data to one list.
You need to handle exceptions when structure does not have same wo to compare.

```
struct ListStruct: Codable {
    let id: String
    let wo: String
    let name: String
    let type: String
    let hightlight:HighlightStruct!
}


func processJSON(_ json: String) {
    do{
        let mydata = Data(json.utf8)
        let decoded = try JSONDecoder().decode(Set<HighlightStruct>.self,from: mydata)
        print(decoded)
        for hl in decoded{
            var filter = structure.filter({$0.wo == hl.wo})
            filter.hightlight = hl
        }
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    
    
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "myCell") as! myCell
    
    let portfolio: ListStruct
    portfolio = structure[indexPath.row]
    
    //Highlight those that match in both arrays
    if portfolio.hightlight?.wo == portfolio.wo {
           cell.backgroundColor = .yellow
    }
```